# How can i install DocsService App programmatically when run app Script code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, libraries

when i use DocsService App show this type of error when i run appS script

> ReferenceError: DocsServiceApp is not defined

I need to install DocsServiceApp in google sheets. I've only seen manual installation I've seen its documentation. but i need to install it programmatically using appScript code

[Doc](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You can try apps script api to change the appscript.json file. Not sure whether it'll work though.  Research it...(I can't provide ready made code)

Comment: You are also going to have to enable two api's viable cloud console and I don't think that's possible in apps script.